# Why $s(1-s)$ numbers which are squares in a field are written $\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}$?

Tags: field-theory

Trying to exercise in Math again after years of other activities, I need a little help on this :

Let $F$ be some arbitrary field with characteristic > 2.

Let $S \subseteq F$ be the set of numbers s such that $s(1-s)=a^2$ for some $a \in F$ , and $s \neq 1$

Let $U \subseteq F$ be the set of numbers of the form $\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}$ for some $u \in F$, and $u^2 \neq -1$

We must show that the $S = U$.

I can easily show that $U \subseteq S$
ut I'm stuck on showing that $S \subseteq U$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\frac{s}{1-s}$ is also a square.

Comment: Thanks, so having $\frac{s}{1-s} = (\frac{s}{a})^2 = u^2$ we check that $s = \frac{u^2}{1+u^2}$ . How did you came up with that idea ?

Comment: $1-s=1/(1+u^2)$, so $ s/(1-s)=u^2/1$, and $s/(1-s)$ is a square away from $s(1-s)$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a straight-edged triangle, with hypotenuse of unit length. Then its height is the

geometric mean of the two segments into which it splits the hypotenuse, $h=\sqrt{s(1-s)}$ .

At the same time, the locus of all points in two-dimensional space which form a straight–

edged triangle with a given hypotenuse is the circle whose diameter that hypotenuse is.

Now, imagine that the circle is centered at the origin. It follows that the height in question

is $r\sin\theta$, where *r* is the radius, and $\theta$ the angle which the radius uniting the point to the

origin forms with the hypotenuse. But $\sin\theta$ can also be written as $\sqrt{\dfrac{\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}}$ , since

$1+\tan^2\theta=\dfrac1{\cos^2\theta}=\sec^2\theta$. See also [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) for more information.

Comment: Was this answer meant to be posted in another question?

Comment: thanks, I see why $h^2 = s(1-s)$ but I've been lost after. Do you suggest that the $u$ i'm searching is somewhat related to the $\tan$ function ?

Comment: @Fluxine: Yes, definitely. Both expressions have obvious trigonometric origins.